# How to solve $\sum_{i=a}^b\sum_{j=i}^c(j-1)$

Tags: summation

I really have looked for about 2 hours on the Internet, but I cannot find how to solve $\sum_{i=a}^b\sum_{j=i}^c(j-1)$. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Can you find these sums: $\sum_{j=i}^c 1$ and $\sum_{j=i}^c i$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, thanks but between the parentheses is $i$

Comment: Even easier to find this sum!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a-b)=n\cdot (a-b)$$

i.e. to say, you have to watch out if the expression contained inside the sigma operator **does at all depend on the variable** ($i$ in the above case)

**Hint 2:**

> The inner summation varies with $j$, but the expression contained in it $(i-1)$ is independent of $j$.

**Hint 3:**

> The inner sum easily reduces to $(c-i+1)\cdot(i-1)$